# How to install PHP 7.2?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, php, owncloud

The title says it all. I'm trying to install PHP7.2 on RPi 3 so I can install OwnCloud on it. When I run `sudo apt-get install php7.2 -y` I get `Unable to locate package php7.2`.

Do I need to add a repo into sources list ?

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using. Raspbian Buster uses PHP 7.3

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Stretch.

Comment: Do I need to switch over to Buster ?

Comment: OwnCloud doesn't support 7.3. 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2 are OK.

Comment: [This website](https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/server/configuration/set-up-owncloud-with-raspberry-pi/) (Ionos) suggests Apache 2, PHP5, and SQLite. I don't know much about PHP or Owncloud, so maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: So does [this one](https://medium.com/@raspberry_pi_hacks/owncloud-on-raspberry-pi-a5ecdefb5510) (Medium.com dated March 13 2020) `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-gd php-xml-parser php5-intl`, then `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite php5-mysql smbclient curl libcurl3 php5-curl` then a bunch of stuff & download a tar.bz2 from Owncloud

Comment: Also Linuxhint [here](https://linuxhint.com/install_owncloud_raspberry_pi/)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I'm still getting `unable to locate php5`. Is Buster distribution a must ?

Comment: Unless you have a special need for an earlier version, I would always use Buster.

Comment: However, try adding this line to your /etc/apt/sources.list file  `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`

Comment: A decision was made not to provide php5 with Stretch since Stretch has moved up to php7. php5 packages were initially placed in the Stretch repository but were removed.  Now the only way to get php5 is to have apt access the Jessie repository by including the Jessie repository in /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: My bad I just double-checked I'm running Buster, not Stretch but getting the error nonetheless. Will try to add the entry into sources list.

Comment: Buster includes php7.3 (but there are no pieces of it installed until you deliberately do that with `sudo apt ...`). To get the basics you need to run `sudo apt install php7.3
php7.3-bz2
php7.3-cli
php7.3-common
php7.3-curl
php7.3-gd
php7.3-json
php7.3-mbstring
php7.3-opcache
php7.3-readline
php7.3-xml
php7.3-zip`

Comment: @Dougie  Thank you for your input. I'll just replace 7.3 with 7.2. As I said above OwnCloud won't work with 7.3

Comment: It won't work - I don't think 7.2 has ever been available for Raspbian (my migrated system has some remnants of 7.1 from Stretch). Just go with 7.3 Owncloud won't care about the differenced in a point release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would move your Pi to Buster and use 7.3 of php.**

Owncloud version 10.3 recommendation is [Apache using php 7.3](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.3/admin_manual/installation/system_requirements.html) as of May 2020.

There is a note in the forum that the current [test build](https://central.owncloud.org/t/server-10-4-0-rc3-release/24442) uses php 7.4

Going by [the php change log](https://www.php.net/) 7.3.18 is the latest release for 7.3 and 7.2.31 for 7.2

If you do need a specific point release then the source code for releases are still available and can be compiled on a Pi if needed. I have broken a Pi though doing this on Jessie so Stretch and Buster where welcomed :)

Comment: I'm gonna try 10.3 because I just installed 10.4.1 and my RPi crashed. Won't boot. Will report back.

Comment: Crashed on 10.3 as well. RPi 3 B+ has only 800 MHz of RAM so I can't be surprised. If I overclock it I'm gonna need a USB fan or something. Better go for RPi 4 with 4GB of RAM.

Comment: It's too bad though. I've got extra RPi 3 and wanted to put in use as a personal cloud. Such a shame. Accepting your answer anyway.